# Flutter pubspec.yaml error: No file or variants found for asset

Tags: flutter, yaml

my problem is that I am getting an error message saying:

`Error detected in pubspec.yaml: No file or variants found for asset: svg/DriverLogoPlain.svg.`

My pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - svg/DriverLogoPlain.svg
```

My path to the svg image:
[PathImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJwni.png)

Anybody has some to this problem solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path in the code is incorrect. You're using `assets/svg/DriverLogoOptimized.svg` as the path in your Dart code, when it should be `svg/DriverLogoOptimized.svg`.

This may just be a copy-paste issue, but YAML is also whitespace sensitive, so you can't have `flutter:` indented so much.

Flutter also doesn't natively support SVGs so beware.

---

With more info from OP their folder was at the incorrect level. Your assets folder is one level too low. Move it to the same level as `android`. Not as a subdirectory.

Comment: Hello sorry for the incorrect error code I added as result of trying different paths in different directories(therefore I added older error code different from .yaml), however the path is correct (see new error code), I also undestand indentions and reformated the question post to look identical to my .yaml

Comment: @Mark Are you using hot reload?

Comment: No, since It wouldn't load and I do not need to do anything else to my app atm, I was trying to fix it without the app running therefore I am comming out of:

 "warning: The asset svg/DriverLogoPlain.svg does not exist. (asset_does_not_exist at [driver] pubspec.yaml:51)" in Dart analysis

Comment: @MarkTheBeat So this is compile-time? You're not even running the app?

Comment: Yes, not running the app at the moment since the error popped-up even without implementing the svg to my code, just to .yaml (I have a plugin for svg support)

Comment: @MarkTheBeat The warning you posted in the comments differs from what you show in your question. Is one runtime and the other static analysis? Provide the output of running `dir` or `ls` or equivalent in your `svg` directory. Edit this output into your question.

Comment: The error in my original post was from the app console, this one is a warning from dart analysis
C:\Users\$user\AndroidStudioProjects\driver>dir svg
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2475-C9F0

 Directory of C:\Users\$user\AndroidStudioProjects\driver

File Not Found

Comment: @MarkTheBeat Your assets folder is one level too low. Move it to the same level as `android`.

Comment: Okay I was a little dummy here, the svg folder was in "Android" module and not the root directory, thanks a lot :D your questions made me realize my mistake <3

Comment: @MarkTheBeat I already said that in a comment and edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that I was typing it before your comment and/or edit of your original reply.